# Get Dropdown value into repeater itemcommand

Tags: asp.net, delegates, repeater

My Repeater `itemdatabound` is call from `oninit()` using delegate.
Now when i call the `item` command of repeater it will call the `OnInit` event.
I have one dropdown box in into repeater. That drop down will bound into `itemdatabound`. So when i select any value from dropdown and click on submit then, it will again call item `databound` and selected index again `0`. So i am not able to get dropdown selected value into `itemcommand`.

```
private void InitializeComponent() {
    this.dgFixedOddsBetList.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(this.Repeater1_ItemDataBound); 
    } 
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
    this.InitializeComponent();
    base.OnInit(e); 
}
```

Comment: We're not physic, we need to see code to be able to help. Please *edit* your question with the appropriate code (please try and cut it down to only the relevant parts)

Comment: private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.dgFixedOddsBetList.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(this.Repeater1_ItemDataBound);
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

Comment: Now **EDIT** you question with the code... not comment!  Include everything that is relevant, including ASPX code, the creation of any dynamic controls, the repeater hander, etc